# Streaming output from program to an arbitrary number of programs under Linux?

Tags: linux, streaming

How should I stream the output from one program to an undefined number of programs in such a fashion that the data isn't buffered anywhere and that the application where the stream originates from doesn't block even if there's nothing reading the stream, but the programs reading the stream do block if there's no output from the first-mentioned program?

I've been trying to Google around for a while now, but all I find is methods where the program does block if nothing is reading the stream.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I stream the output from one program to an undefined number of programs in such a fashion that the data isn't buffered anywhere and that the application where the stream originates from doesn't block even if there's nothing reading the stream

Your requirements as stated can not possibly be satisfied without some form of a buffer.

Most straightforward option is to write the output to the file and let consumers read that file.

Another option is to have a ring-buffer in a form of a memory mapped file. As the capacity of a ring-buffer is normally fixed there needs to be a policy for dealing with slow consumers. Options are: block the producer; terminate the slow consumer; let the slow consumer somehow recover when it missed data.

Comment: The issue is that the output cannot be stored to a static file. It's streaming data and it keeps changing over time. It'd fill the drive in no time.

Comment: @WereCatf Then you definitely need a ring-buffer which I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I wrote something like what you describe for an audio stream processing app (http://hewgill.com/nwr/). It's on github as [splitter.cpp](https://github.com/ghewgill/nwr/blob/master/splitter.cpp) and has a small [man page](http://hewgill.com/nwr/splitter).

The `splitter` program currently does not support dynamically changing the set of output programs. The output programs are fixed when the command is started.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really solve my problem then. I would've thought there did exist a solution for this kind of a problem already, but maybe it's just too much of a fringe-case for that. I s'spose I'll take a look at your code if no one can provide me with another solution. Thank you anyways for your response!

Comment: @WereCatf: So, you're saying that you *do* need to dynamically change the set of output programs? I wasn't clear on that point from reading your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I did use the words "arbitrary" and "undefined number" in an effort to get that need across. My apologizes for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what sort of data you are talking about (how large is the data, what format is it, etc, etc) it is hard to come up with a concrete answer. Let's say for example you want a "ticker-tape" application that sends out information for share purchases on the stock exchange, you could quite easily have a server that accepts a socket from each application, starts a thread and sends the relevant data as it appears from the recoder at the stock market. I'm not aware of any "multiplexer" that exists today (but Greg's one may be a starting point). If you use (for example) XML to package the data, you could send the second half of a packet, and the client code would detect that it's not complete, so throws it away.

If, on the other hand, you are sending out high detail live update weather maps for the whole country, the data is probably large enough that you don't want to wait for a full new one to arrive, so you need some sort of lock'n'load protocol that sets the current updated map, and then sends that one out until (say) 1 minute later you have a new one. Again, it's not that complex to write some code to do this, but it's quite a different set of code to the "ticker tape" solution above, because the packet of data is larger, and getting "half a packet" is quite wasteful and completely useless.

If you are streaming live video from the 2016 Olympics in Brazil, then you probably want a further diffferent solution, as timing is everything with video, and you need the client to buffer, pick up key-frames, throw away "stale" frames, etc, etc, and the server will have to be different.